# Ionic Cordova web app cookies not being stored on Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cookies

My company has built a medium size Ionic application and now we're trying to make available natively for Android and iOS and I'm having an issue with persisting cookies.

When running the application Safari there are no issues at all, cookies persist just fine, but when building for devices, the cookies are not being persisted.

The way things work now is when a user logs in, a cookie is returned from the server.  After this, the cookie should be sent with every subsequent request, ensuring that the user is still logged in.  When I look at the initial response from the server after login, the 'set-cookie' header is there.  However, all requests afterward don't contain the cookie, so the server returns a response of not logged in. This only happens when running natively on iOS or Android.

When I debug to see if the cookies are being persisted, I see that there are no cookies.

I know there was a similar issue with iOS 13, but I'm not using iOS 13, I'm using iOS 12.  And my problem is on both Android and iOS.  When doing Google searches, all the workarounds I see are for problems that are not the same as the one I'm having, and I've tried those workarounds anyways, and they don't work.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Any ideas on what this might be and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated, I haven't gotten anywhere and I've been searching for an answer for days now.

Also too, because the cookie is HttpOnly I'm not able to access using TypeScript, so I can't persist the cookie manually without sending a non-HttpOnly cookie. Which isn't really an option at the moment.

Comment: I recently ran into this issue.  I use universal-cookies for my hybrid app.  On desktop everything works fine.  On android I found that document.cookies would not set If options are present in the string value...  Removing options in my call to cookies.set() allowed cookies to be set.  Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

i had some troubles with cookies and cordova too .

In my case, the plugin cordova-plugin-cartegraph-cookie-master helped me to get and set cookies.

**Source Plugin:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cartegraph-cookie-master

**Install :**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cartegraph-cookie-master
```

**Usage :
Get cookie value :**

```
cookieMaster.getCookieValue('http://<some host>:<some port>', '<cookie name>', function(data) {
  console.log(data.cookieValue);
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

**Set cookie value :**

```
cookieMaster.setCookieValue('http://<some host>:<some port>', '<cookie name>', '<cookie value>',
    function() {
        console.log('A cookie has been set');
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log('Error setting cookie: '+error);
    });
```

Comment: how did you use this cordova plugin with ionic